# Mobile app doesn't open dialog for select web browsers

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, mobile

I'm creating mobile app with HTML/CSS/JS (phoneap, jquery mobile) and I'm converting code which is here https://build.phonegap.com/apps.

I need to achieve this behaviour:
after clicking on the link, which links on a external page, I need to open a question for selection a browser.
This si my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Page Title</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/datapicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jPayPalCart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/datapicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.css" /> 

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function openDialog() {
                 window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');

            }
        </script>


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.timepicker.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head> 
    <body> 

    <!-- Start of first page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="findShop">


        <div data-role="content">   

            <div class="container" data-role="content" role="main">
                <div class="row main-page">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 title">
                        Die vielleicht beste Pizza der Stadt!
                        <a href="#" onclick="openDialog();">Open in web browser</a> 

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know where could be problem

Comment: If you used inAppBrowser to load external links in a browser and you have multiple browsers in your device , it will ask your browser preference. Are you using phonegap-1.2.0.js? Then you cant use inAppBrowser. Update your cordova version and try

Comment: I included external inAppBrowser. I downloaded new cordova version and included but nothing changed.